# Budget Capping in horizontal scaling

Tags: java, distributed, distributed-computing, distributed-caching, distributed-system

I am building a web service that answers specific number of requests per day for different registered users. Each user has a daily quota so i need to meet those constraints.

I have planned to scale it horizontally by adding more servers and load balancing in a round-robin manner.

I will have one distributed database which has distributed counters. This database will be used to only report the counts each day.

Servers will handle 2 to 3k requests per second. So they need the most updated count of the exhausted quota when serving each request so as not to exceed the quota.

I want to prevent any out of process call from each server so that the latency in serving requests is low.

I have been thinking in terms of dividing the quota between all the servers and maintaining a per server quota constraint in-memory. But how would i deal with server failures, restarts ?

Is it better to do out of process such as query another database over the network from each server ? What i have observed is that the latency would increase drastically in this case.

Please advice if i am going in the correct direction ?

Answer (score 0):

Sharding the quota is a perfectly acceptable way of accomplishing this. Many online services partition the quota based on how the data is divided. For example, I believe DynamoDB partitions quota based on hash-key because that's the way they physically divide the data.

Another thing to consider: how much of a sin is it to go over the global quota? Does it mess with billing? Would it kill some service you depend on?

In the service I build/maintain I shard transaction quota across the servers and each server periodically updates it's estimate of how many servers there are. I don't care about billing, but protecting an underlying resource. As such, I've calculated how much throughput the resource can handle during a bad networking event and based the quotas on that.

---

You'll notice that you are making a CAP-theorem based decision here. How consistent, available, and partition tolerant do you want the quotas?. Which of these three constraints can you loosen to meet your clients' needs? (Your clients include your dependencies in this case.)